# Find first file in directory with Java

Tags: java, io, java-io

I have some sort of batch program that should pick up a file from a directory and process it.

Since this program is supposed to:

- run on JDK 5,
- be small (no external libraries)
- and fast! (with a bang)

...**what is the best way to only pick one file from the directory - without using** `File.list()` (might be hundreds of files)?

Comment: Do you want to pick up a named file/directory or any file? Also, after processing that file, do you move on to others or just exit the program?

Comment: So to be clear, do you need to get a file (any file) from the directory or do you just want to know if the directory contains a file?

Comment: just any file really, the first that is found - the program should do this while there are files in the directory (files are added continuously); I just don't want to list all the files in the folder each time, seems very inefficient...

Comment: There is no good solution here on Java 1.5, you can use a filter to get only 1 file, but then java will only return one file but parse over all of them anyways.

Comment: What is it about a File that makes it 'first'?  Earliest creation date?  1st in sorted order by name?  Smallest in size?  BTW - have you measured the time it takes to list 100s of files, are you just WAGing this premature optimization?

Comment: about 'first': you're right, "any" would have been a better word; 
about performance: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4285834

Comment: @AndrewThompson read how this works in Pascal (FindFirstFile) They have all the explanations.

Comment: @AndrewThompson And it is present in c++, too. And all is based on the FindFirstFile in Win32 Api. It is more primitive, but much more powerful, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java 7 you could use a [DirectoryStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html), but in Java 5, the only ways to get directory entries are `list()` and `listFiles()`.

Note that listing a directory with hundreds of files is not ideal but still probably no big deal compared to processing one of the files. But it would probably start to be problematic once the directory contains many thousands of files.

Comment: Your point about big directories is very true.  But these cause problems for lots of things apart from Java.  The best approach is not to put huge numbers of files into a single directory.

Comment: best answer, short and sweet :)

Comment: DirectoryStream is the Interface, we cannot use it for any work, including getting a file.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `FileFilter` (or `FilenameFilter`) written to accept only once, for example:

```
File dir = new File("/some/dir");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    boolean first = true;
    public boolean accept(final File pathname) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: True enough, but it does avoid the overhead of creating and returning an entire array of `File` or filename objects.

Answer (score 2):

It seems from what you said that you want to process every file in the directory once (including files that get added to the directory). You can do the following: set a monitor on the directory that generates notifications when files are added. you then process each file that you get notified about. Since you use JDK 5 , i suggest using [jpathwatch](http://jpathwatch.wordpress.com) . note that you need to make sure the file writing has finished before trying to process it. after starting the monitor to insure you will be processing every new file, make a one time usage of  file listing to process the current content.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My implementation made use of .list() as you said it wouldn't but It may hold some value anyways :)

If you look at the File implementation public String[] list() method seems to have less overhead than File[] listFiles(). So fastest should be

```
String[] ss = myDir.list();
File toProcess = null;
for(int i = o ; i< ss.length ; i++){
 toProcess = new File(myDir.list()[i], myDir));
 if(toProcess.isFile())break;
}
```

From File.class

```
public File[] listFiles() {
String[] ss = list();
if (ss == null) return null;
int n = ss.length;
File[] fs = new File[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fs[i] = new File(ss[i], this);
}
return fs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If one look at the class class FileSystem which it boils down to for filesystem access there is only the list method so there seems to be no other way in "pure" JAVA to select a file than to list them all in a String array.

Answer (score -1):

There is no good solution here on Java 1.5, you can use a filter to get only 1 file, but then java will only return one file but parse over all of them anyways. If you don't need the actual file object you could try something like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dir")` split the returned string on `\n` and print out the first line :-P